# Syncing Sublime Text 2 to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

Good morning,

I am currently following a tutorial video on ruby on rails.  I created a server and my next step is to view the files associated with my server in sublime text 2.  In the video, all the instructor does is open sublime text 2 and all the files/folders are already loaded.  When I open sublime text 2, I get a blank document.  I think I need to do something related to this link: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html but I really don't understand the lingo or how to go about using those commands. Whenever I use them I get "command not found"  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open up Sublime Text 2

Then go to the menu bar and click -> Project, then select -> Add folder to project.  From the pop up select your app folder and you should see all the files there :)

Hope this helps